# How do I set event methods for programmatically created combo boxes?

Tags: c#, combobox, wpf-controls

I am creating small program that has dynamically created combo boxes. Each time the user opens the program, based on some context, there could be 3-30 items that need 4 drop down lists for selection. I am creating these based off of the following code, which is just a snippet.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            s.Children.Add(new ComboBox()
            {
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                Margin = new Thickness(m, -25, 0, 0),
                Width = 75,
                Height = 25,
                FontSize = 12,
                Name = "obj1_" + i.ToString(),
                ItemsSource = objs,
            });

            m = m + 50;

            s.Children.Add(new Label()
            {
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                Margin = new Thickness(m, -25, 0, 0),
                Width = 25,
                Height = 25,
                FontSize = 12,
                Name = "lbl1_" + i.ToString(),
            });
         }
```

s is a stack panel that I am adding each of the combo boxes too. The ItemSource is from a small method elsewhere to figure out which list should go into the drop down.

My question is, how do I call the events for these created combo boxes? Trying

```
        private void obj1_1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox this_box = (ComboBox)sender;
            lbl1_1.Content = "!!!";
        }
```

works well enough but the label doesn't exist in the current context.

Also, am I creating the boxes and labels the best way for this type of scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another method could be to create all the controls at design time (& set event handlers). On startup, hide the ones that aren't needed.

Comment: Paul, do you mean create all of the boxes in XAML initially and then add the code for each of them?

Comment: That's it - you may have a common event handler, with a switch statement to select which label to update or individual handlers for each. That way you avoid the problem of the label not existing when you write the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside you for loop
1)Create an new Panel
2)Add the label and combo to that panel
3)Add the newly created panel to s

Inside your obj1_1_SelectionChanged event:
1)Find the Parent control of the ComboBox
2)Search for the label inside its Children and update its text

**Solution 2**

When you create your controls create a Guid (or an int) and set the Tag property of your controls to that object.
Now when you are on a combo you can search your Window for the label with the same Tag

```
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

            s.Children.Add(new ComboBox()
            {
                Tag = g
            });

            s.Children.Add(new Label()
            {
                Tag = g
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's clever. I haven't used a Guid before. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: @dooms13 You don't new a Guid ,any unique object will do ,you could use the i variable of the for if you want ( if you don't create more controls later)